# Update the url angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I have a stepper. On the stepper I have the following url: localhost:4200/new-form. After submitting the first form, I get from backend publicId, which I should set in my url (localhost:4200/new-form/publicId)
I try to do it, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
            return this.dataService
        .putData(this.formData)
        .pipe(
            tap(res => {
                console.log(res.publicId)
                if (res.publicId) {
                    this.authService.setPublicId(res.publicId);
                    this._router.navigate([], {
                        relativeTo: this._route,
                        queryParams: {
                            publicId: res.publicId
                        },
                        queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
                        skipLocationChange: true,

                    });
                    console.log(this._router.url);
                }
                this.isStepCompleted = true;
            }),
this._router.url is : "/new-form?publicId=%22svvJGIICIGtEEtBBrDtBFAHErwGIvFCv%22" 
expected result: "/new-form/svvJGIICIGtEEtBBrDtBFAHErwGIvFCv"
```

Comment: Try this: `this._router.navigate([res.publicId], {  relativeTo: this._route, skipLocationChange:true})`

Comment: Looks like you're trying to route to the same page just with a `publickId` param this time, is that correct?

Comment: benshabatnoam, yes, you're right

Comment: @David, in this case, _router.url is /new-form

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have used query params, these are different to the router parameters you are expecting. Try passing the `publicId` into your navigate function as part of the url, for example `this._router.navigate([res.publicId])`

Answer (score 0):

Angular router doesn't reconstruct or refresh the page when navigating to the same component. In other words, navigate to the same component won't fire the component's constructor or ngOnInit function.

After that said, this is what I suggests you should do:

First, create an `init()` function where you'll execute the *refresh* logic of your component.

Second, you can execute this `init()` functions in 2 ways:

1. Use the `init()` function in your data service subscription (where you're navigating using the parameter)

```
return this.dataService
        .putData(this.formData)
        .pipe(
            tap(res => {
                console.log(res.publicId)
                if (res.publicId) {
                    this.authService.setPublicId(res.publicId);
                    this._router.navigate([], {
                        relativeTo: this._route,
                        queryParams: {
                            publicId: res.publicId
                        },
                        queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
                        skipLocationChange: true,

                    });
                    console.log(this._router.url);
                    this.init();   // <----------------- here you'll call the init function
                }
                this.isStepCompleted = true;
            })
```

**OR**

2.
Inject `ActivatedRoute` in the component's constructor and use it to subscribe to query params changes where you'll execute the `init()` function.

```
constructor(private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    activateRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.init()
      // here you'll get the parameter like this: params['publicId']);
    })
  }
```